# Play Framework 2.6 in Production mode doesn't seem to be doing anything

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to set up a play framework 2.6 application in production, but I'm struggling a bit with it.

I've tried both `sbt dist` and `sbt stage`, but when I run the server startup file with -Dplay.http.secret.key (generated as per https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret), nothing really happens. I simply get a prompt with `>`, and if I check the logs, there's nothing happening there.

It doesn't seem the server is up at all. I tried http://localhost:9000, as well as https://localhost:9443, but I get the usual "Site can't be reached".

I tried to set up the property file myself with `-Dconfig.resource` and `-Dconfig.file`. I also made sure I had execution permission for my startup file.

None of it worked. What am I missing? Any extra configuration I need to specify to run it in production, either in build.sbt or application.properties?

I increased Play logging level to debug, and still see absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you quote the secret ? The secret usually contains chars that have a special meaning in a shell, so you need to quote :

./app -Dplay.http.secret.key='M%>secret^^%%'

You're also free to put the secret in the application.conf.

Comment: I'll be damned. Tried without quotes and with double quotes, didn't think about trying single quotes. It worked!!! Thanks

Comment: Double quotes still makes the shell interpret certain special chars. Single quotes basically make it a string literal.